# What is the most efficient way to create a distinct list of items using .NET?

Tags: .net, sorting, ienumerable, distinct-values

I have a large list of values (100-200 character strings) and I need to return a distinct listing of them.  What is the most efficient way to do this using .NET?  The 2 ways that I can think of are:

1. Use the Distinct() method of the IEnumerable class
2. Use a Dictionary

If the Dictionary approach is faster in raw terms, consider a trade-off decision around maintainability of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would expect `Enumerable.Distinct` to be about as fast as using a dictionary if you're only doing it once. If you want to be able to add/remove values and keep the distinct-ness, you could build a `HashSet<string>` (which is basically what I expect Distinct is doing under the hood, but `Distinct()` will obviously return new values as it finds them, maintaining order.

In fact, just using:

```
HashSet<string> distinctItems = new HashSet<string>(list);
```

will be a pretty good (and simple) solution if you don't mind the ordering being messed up. It's simpler than using a `Dictionary`, and conceptually cleaner as well (as you don't *really* want to map keys to values).

(As ever, I would suggest finding the most readable solution first, and benchmark it - if it's "fast enough" then go with that. If you want to use this as part of another query, then `Distinct` may well be the most readable way. Otherwise, I'd suggest `HashSet`.)

Answer (score 2):

I would personally go with the Distinct() method provided by LINQ. It's far easier to read and maintain. Whilst using LINQ will be slower than using a dictionary the difference will be small (in the case you've listed) and you'd be better spending time optimizing database queries or web service calls.

Answer (score 1):

I would siggest you to use profiling here. Generate a list with sample items, sort it say 1M times using both ways, and measure the time used by each way.

If readability is a concern, create a `GetDistinctItems` method and put your code inside it: voilà, self-documented code.